# How to create a logo of firefox addon by addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created my firefox addon but when I install it, it doesn't create any icon on the tool bar of firefox.

I am unable to upload the image due to low reputation but posted the image at [this link](http://postimg.org/image/ennkoev6b/)

Comment: You didn't provide any code whatsoever, or any other details such as error messages, so it is impossible to help you.

Comment: You have to use CustomizableUI.jsm examples are seen here: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/06/australis-for-add-on-developers-2/

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess you're using the add-on SDK because of the tag. To do this, use ActionButton:

```
let { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

let button = ActionButton({
  id: "my-button-id",
  label: "Button Label",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon16.png",
    "32": "./icon32.png"
  },
  onClick: function(state) {
    console.log("button '" + state.label + "' was clicked");

  }
});
```

[The full documentation is here[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action)

Pay particular attention to the docs on icon files - files should be located in the data sub-directory in your add-on folder.

If you're not actually using the Add-on SDK, Noitidart's comment is more relevant to you.